# I can't get into my desktop, problems with systemd-networkd

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd-networkd

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 for a few months now, so I'm pretty new here. I get this error when I boot up my laptop:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
See 'systemctl status networkd-dispatcher.service' for details.
```

I went into recovery mode and ran the command suggested in the error output as root. I got this:

```
# systemctl status networkd-dispatcher.service
systemd-networkd.service - Network service
Loaded: loaded(/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive(dead)
Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
```

I've been googling all around and no luck so far. I gave up and decided to ask help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you type `systemctl enable systemd-networkd` into the recovery mode terminal?

Comment: Now it gave me networkd-dispatcher; enabled.

Comment: But still same problem at booting screen [FAILED]. Do i have to refresh/update something for it to take effect?

Comment: Okay so after enabling it, try starting it. `systemctl start systemd-networkd` and right after that check the status. Iff that is not informative and helpful try also `journalctl -r`. This will give you a system log listing starting with the most recent entries. `ip address show` will check if you've an IP address. If you have a connection, try `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. You may have a broken package.